# Chisel3 REPL peek value is correct but expect fails in test

Tags: fpga, chisel, digital-logic

I am using Chisel3 to build my circuit, and I have the following test

```
  reset()

  private val inputData = IndexedSeq.fill(ProcedureSpaceSize)(0: BigInt)
    .patch(0, Seq(63: BigInt), 1)
    .patch(1, Seq(65: BigInt), 1)
    .patch(2, Seq(98: BigInt), 1)
    .patch(3, Seq(98: BigInt), 1)
  poke(sff.io.inputDataVector, inputData)

  step(1)

  expect(sff.io.done, true)
  expect(sff.io.ret, 65) // fails
```

Now I keep getting fails on the second `expect`. However, when I try to run my circuit in REPL and use `peek` to look at the values of `io_ret` after stepping through the same procedures according to the test, I get the correct value which is 65.

My question is simply, why am I getting failure in Chisel test but can peek the right results when debugging in REPL mode? Is it not a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
circuit code

```
class SFF extends Module {

  private val dataType = Integer32Bit

  // IO
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    // INPUT
    val inputDataVector: Vec[UInt] = Input(Vec(ProcedureSpaceSize, dataType))

    // OUTPUT
    val ret: UInt = Output(dataType)
    val done: Bool = Output(Bool())
  })

  // WIRE
  val data: Vec[UInt] = Wire(Vec(ProcedureSpaceSize, dataType))
  data := io.inputDataVector
  val paramB: UInt = Wire(dataType)
  paramB := data(1)
  io.ret := DontCare

  // LOGIC
  io.done := true.B
  io.ret := paramB

}
```

Comment: Which REPL are you referring to? Can you share the circuit or a relevant portion of the circuit?

Comment: @ChickMarkley I attached my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I think the problem is. For historical reasons `poke` of a vector reverses the order of elements during the poke, and that is why you are seeing the wrong value for your return. When you used the REPL you probably did your `poke`s discretely so they went in the expected places.

I used the "-tiv" treadle flag to see what the simulator was doing.

The Chisel development team is planning on adding Vec literals which should prevent this in the future.

I'd also recommend trying [ChiselTest](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers2), it's a more modern version of a unit tester. It does not have a `poke` for `Vec` types which would protect you against this error. When `Vec` literals are implemented they will be available in ChiselTest, probably not in iotesters.

Comment: Interesting. I reversed the input vector, and it indeed worked! I tried the newest Chisel test vector literal, but I just couldn't get it to work for some reason; namely, I couldn't get to use `.Lit()` on my own datatypes despite that it works perfectly on official examples. I think I will just live with the reverse Seq trick for now.